# Add EditText dynamically to ListView row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

after a long click on a list view item (a list view row contains of only one TextView), a dynamically created EditText is supposed to appear in the corresponding list view row. How do I manage to do do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to extend an `ArrayAdapter` (if you haven't done yet), and do that in the `getView()` method.

The second of this method's parameters is a `View` (usually called `convertView`, but not necessarily). Speaking very vaguely, this `View` represents actually the current row's layout, so you'll need to add the `EditText` into this method.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  LinearLayout rootLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root_ll);

  EditText et = new EditText(this);
  // Set additional parameters to et
  ...

  rootLinearLayout.addView(et);

  ...
  return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to tell the ArrayAdapter which option was chosen in onContextItemSelected()? Depending on this option I want to add the EditTest only to a specific row.

Comment: You can declare a `public` method in your `ArrayAdapter` so you can call `adapter.setMyOption(chosenOption)` from your `Activity`, but I think that the best way you can customize each row is inside your `getView()` method and do the logic here. Simply check whether some condition happens and depending on it, show or not the `EditText`.